# iOS Metal: The fastest way to read read-only data?

Tags: ios, ios10, metal, compute-shader

**Situation:**
In a Metal kernel function, every thread in a threadgroup reads the exact same value at a time. The kernel pseudocode:

```
kernel void foo(device   int2*   ranges,  
                constant float3& readonlyBuffer,  
                device   float*  results,  
                uint lno [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]])  
{  
  float acc = 0.0;  

  for(int i=ranges[lno].x; i<ranges[lno].y; i++) {  
    // each thread in threadgroup processes the same value from the buffer  
    acc += process( readonlyBuffer[i] );  
  }  

  results[...] = acc;  
}
```

**The problem:** in the pursuit of optimizing buffer reads, I changed `readonlyBuffer`'s address space qualifier from `device` to `constant`. This had zero impact on the kernel performance although the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/func-var-qual/func-var-qual.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH4-SW6) says something different:

> The constant address space is optimized for multiple instances executing a graphics or kernel function accessing the same location in the buffer.

**Questions:**

- How can I improve memory read times of my constant buffer?
- Can I move the buffer (or at least a part of it) to an on-chip cache (something like [Constant Buffer Preloading](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/606oluchfgwakjbymy8/606/606_advanced_metal_shader_optimization.pdf) (page 24))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example code, indexing into `readonlyBuffer` would generate a compiler error.

Assuming `readonlyBuffer` is declared as a pointer, then the compiler doesn't statically know the size, and can't move the data to the constant memory space.

If `readonlyBuffer` is small (you only have 4KB of constant memory to work with), put it into a struct as follows:

```
struct ReadonlyBuffer {
    float3 values[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
};
```

Then do:

```
kernel void foo(device   int2*   ranges,  
                constant ReadonlyBuffer& readonlyBuffer,  
                device   float*  results,  
                uint lno [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]])
```

Finally, run a GPU trace ("Capture GPU Frame") and ensure you don't get the following error:

> The Compiler was not able to Preload your Buffer. Kernel Function,
>   Buffer Index: 1.

For more info about Buffer Preloading, see: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/606/?time=408